# Original and restored RSA public keys are identical, but their X509 encoded representations are not?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I'm generating 2048-bit RSA public and private keys, encoding them in X509 format, converting the result to PKCS#1 format, encoding that as a Base64 string and saving it in a database. Then I retrieve the string from the database, restore it to PKCS#1 format, convert it to X509 format, and then restore the public key object.

When I call println() on the original and the restored public key objects, I confirm that they have the same modulus and public exponent. When I check their equality with .equals(), the assertion returns true. However, when I compare the X509 encoded representation of the original public key object and that of the restored public key object, they are different. This is problematic for me because I use a hash derived from this value in order to identify the keys.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

I must store keys in the database in PKCS#1 format because the database file will be moved to an iOS device the keys will be restored there, and [Apple's Security framework only allows the export or import of RSA keys in PKCS#1 format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_as_data).

I'm using Kotlin on JVM; the code below reproduces the issue:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERNull
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.KeyPair
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator
import java.security.PublicKey
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec
import java.util.*
import kotlin.test.Test

class IssueExample {

    @Test
    fun demonstrateProblem() {
        //Generate RSA key pair
        val keyPairGenerator: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048)
        val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()

        //Convert public key to X509, then to PKCS1 format
        val pubKeyX509Bytes = keyPair.public.encoded
        val sPubKeyInfo: SubjectPublicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(pubKeyX509Bytes)
        val pubKeyPrimitive: ASN1Primitive = sPubKeyInfo.parsePublicKey()
        val pubKeyPkcs1Bytes: ByteArray = pubKeyPrimitive.encoded

        //Convert PKCS1 to Base64 string
        val encoder = Base64.getEncoder()
        val base64PubKey = encoder.encodeToString(pubKeyX509Bytes)

        //Restore Base64 string to PKCS#1
        val decoder = Base64.getDecoder()
        val restoredPubKeyPKCS1Bytes = decoder.decode(base64PubKey)

        //Restore PKCS#1 to X509
        val algorithmIdentifier: AlgorithmIdentifier = AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, DERNull.INSTANCE);
        val restoredPubKeyX509Bytes: ByteArray = SubjectPublicKeyInfo(algorithmIdentifier, pubKeyPkcs1Bytes).encoded

        //Restore X509 tp public key
        val restoredPubKey: PublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKeyX509Bytes))

        //Comparing the two public key objects returns true
        println(restoredPubKey.equals(keyPair.public))
        //And calling println() yields identical results for both
        println(restoredPubKey)
        println(keyPair.public)
        //Yet their X509 representations return false!!
        println(restoredPubKey.encoded.equals(keyPair.public.encoded))
        println(restoredPubKey.encoded)
        println(keyPair.public.encoded)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try dumping the encodings with e.g. OpenSSL asn1parse; with a little luck that will show if there are structural differences

Comment: I'm not an expert in Kotlin but in Java `.equals` on arrays is not what you think it is. For that matter neither is `.toString()` or whatever it's called in Kotlin, so the last two lines don't print anything meaningful. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12292513/238704. Replace the 3rd line from the botton with `println(Arrays.equals(restoredPubKey.encoded, keyPair.public.encoded))` and it prints true.

Comment: I tried @clausc 's suggestion and couldn't find structural differences; the original and restored keys' encoded representations did actually match, but I'm new to Kotlin and I was comparing them incorrectly. I implemented @
President James K. Polk 's fix and that revealed the issue. Everything is now working properly; thank you both for your help.