# Immutable map with String[] as key not returning value for correct key

Tags: java

I am using ImmutableMap in my very simple code. At one point I am trying to return value corresponding to a key which is an array of string with only 1 value "1234". Here's a screenshot of debugging step:

[image: Debugger with key that I pass and candidate key that is being checked in ImmutableMap. Notice they're the same]

However, I get no value and keys don't match.
Here's candidateKey in debugger:
[image]

Here's my key in debugger:
[image]

Here's debugger saying they're not equal!
[image]

It's driving me nuts. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you are directly comparing the array objects and not the contents with .equals, you should probably try the Arrays utility `Arrays.equals()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Array HashCode implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744735/java-array-hashcode-implementation)

Comment: In brief, Java arrays don’t implement `equals` and `hashCode` in a useful way, and should generally not be used as hash keys. Try `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overide equals for array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292513/how-to-overide-equals-for-array-in-java)

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.equals()` is right when comparing strings, but when you use that method on two `String[]` then you are really back to comparing the object references. If you want to compare the contents of two String arrays against each other then you can use `Arrays.equals(Object[] a1,Object[] a2)`. The docs [are here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object%5B%5D)), but basically that will compare the length of each array and then make sure they contain the same items.

In the end, your code would become something like:

```java
if (Arrays.equals(key, candidateKey)) {
  return entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: But all I am doing is calling get() on ImmutableMap from a library. This equals call is while debugging into the method in the library. Does that mean that it's expected not to use String[] as key?

Comment: Using an array as a key is kind of unusual. It might make sense for your use case, but more typically you see things like `Map<String, List<String>>` where the key is a single object and the value is a list. That said, if you are using `Map.Entry` or something similar you could still do something like `Arrays.equals(entry.getKey(), candidateKey)`.

Comment: @Maxsteel It's not so much that it's not expected to use `String[]` for the key, it's that arrays use the default `equals` implementation from `Object`, which tests reference equality. Since the [map interface relies on a correct `equals` implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)), you using `String[]` for the key breaks things. But this would be true for **any** type that does not provide a valid (in this context) implementation of `equals`. And, if your map implementation relies on it, the same applies to `hashCode`.

Comment: @Maxsteel If your domain demands the `String[]` be the key, just wrap the array in a custom object that defines `equals` (and in all likelihood `hashCode`) to be based on the array. Then use that custom object as the key of your map. Or use a `List<String>` instead (easily created with `Arrays.asList(array)`). Though keep in mind that it's typically important to never modify a mutable key once it's been placed in a map, especially if that map is hash based.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this question for the reason why this doesn't work:
[equals vs Arrays.equals in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java)

Essentially, you are comparing the memory address of the arrays. The `java.util.Arrays.equals` method will compare whether the length is the same and each objects `equals` method returns true for the values. Since string `equals` method compares the chars, then they will return true and this will give you the result you are looking for.

If you continue and change this into an array of objects, then it will depend on how the class implements the `equals` method. If you leave the implementation as the default, then it will only compare memory address (use `==`) and would return false if they weren't the same reference.