# Is it possible to make a Java object 'reflect' a primitive type?

Tags: java, object, primitive-types

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class Value
{
    private String label;
    private double value;

    public Value(String label, double value)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;   
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Now given the following instances:

```
Value v1 = new Value("first value", 5);
Value v2 = new Value("first value", 6);
```

Is there some way to alias

```
double sum = v1.getValue() + v2.getValue();
```

with

```
double sum = v1 + v2;
```

?

Classes like Double and Integer already have this functionality. So (how can we add it | why can't we add it) to our own classes?

Comment: i guess you are looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598707/operator-overloading-and-overriding-in-java)?

Comment: This would be overloading of operators, which you cannot do in Java.

Comment: "Classes like Double and Integer already have this functionality." Not really. They have auto-unboxing and auto-boxing functionality, that's all.

Comment: "Classes like Double and Integer already have this functionality." That's because they get an unfair help from Java compiler.

Comment: @JonSkeet Try to unbox your terms the next time; 
That way they can provide information that does explain the problem's context without providing references of unknown compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't. In Java there's no possible way to overload the built-in operators.

You mentioned that this is valid for the wrapper types (like `Integer`, `Double`, etc.), but this is not exactly true. When the operator is applied to such types, in the background a process, called un-boxing, is started, so that `Double` is turned to `double`, `Integer` to `int` and so on.

Comment: I understand.

And I guess, there isn't a way to define an unboxing behavior for custom classes?

Comment: Yes, we can't alter the unboxing behavior to support custom types.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned this is called *operator overloading* and is not supported by Java. Also it's not to be confused with default unboxing of `Integer` and `Double`.

If calling getter methods on objects is a big issue for you i suggest you create a coupld of methods like:

```
private double add(Value... values){
    double sum = 0;
    for(Value val: values) 
        sum += val.getValue();
    return sum;
}
private double multiply(Value... values){
    double product = 1;
    for(Value val: values) 
        sum *= val.getValue();
    return product;
}
```

and so on...

So now you can do

```
double sum = add(v1,v2,v3,v4);
double product = multiply(v1,v2,v3);
```

and so on...

I think this is the closest thing to what you asked.