# Java - Overwriting existing function

Tags: java

Is there a way on "Rewriting" a function.
Pseudo:

```
function a() {print "B"}
function a() {print "C"}
```

Output: `C`

Comment: What do you mean by "rewriting" a function ? Do you mean in the same class ? In a children class ?

Comment: You can [override](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm).

Comment: You can override methods in subclasses and overload methods (redefine w/ different arguments).

Comment: In a children class.

Comment: Are you asking if Java supports inheritance?

Comment: On a side note: You certainly can't do this if your function happens to be an [operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598707/operator-overloading-and-overriding-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overriding

```
class MyClass {
    public void myMethod () {
        System.out.println("MyClass");
    }
}

class MySubClass extends MyClass {
    @Override
    public void myMethod () {
        System.out.println("MySubClass");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MyClass a = new MyClass();
        a.myMethod(); // "MyClass"
        MySubClass b = new MySubClass();
        b.myMethod(); // "MySubClass"
    }
}
```

In this example, `MySubClass` overrides the inherited method `myMethod`.

### Overloading

```
class MyClass {
    public void myMethod () {
        System.out.println("myMethod");
    }

    public void myMethod (int i) {
        System.out.println(i * 2);
    }

    public void myMethod (String s) {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + s);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MyClass a = new MyClass();
        a.myMethod(); // "myMethod"
        a.myMethod(33); // "66"
        a.myMethod("Jeremy") // "Hello, Jeremy"
    }
}
```

In this example, `MyClass` has multiple definitions of the method `myMethod`, but they accept different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Simply rewrite the method in its subclass.

```
public class Something {
    public Something() {
    }
    public void printHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}

public class SomethingElse extends Something {
    public SomethingElse() {
    }
    public void printHi() {
        System.out.println("I refuse to say hi!");
    }
}

Something something = new Something();
something.printHi(); // prints Hi

SomethingElse somethingElse = new SomethingElse();
somethingElse.printHi(); // prints I refuse to say hi!
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the annotation? I remember not having to do that when learning Java a few years ago. Is it a new release that requires it?

Comment: Turns out you don't. Edited.

Comment: @Gendarme [When do you use Java's @ Override annotation and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/94361). So even though is isn't mandatory you _should_ use it. So the last edit of this answer is a good example for how you _should not_ do it.

Comment: @Tom The reasons given in the answer in your link are fine I guess. But not important enough to impose a must-do practice of using that annotation. Using it to avoid typos does not make sense. And if a method has a hard parameter-list to keep track of it is probably badly written code. However, this discussion is off-topic so I will stop here. Your link is useful and appreciated, though.

Comment: @Gendarme "However, this discussion is off-topic so I will stop here.": Since your arguments are kind of weak (I hope you're just very new to programming), I appreciate that. :).